# Как получить массив байтов при хешировании

Tags: php

Мне нужно получить массив байтов, чтобы потом байты обработать, но я немогу етого сделать так как `$ar = hash_hmac('sha512', $hash, $salt, false);`
Не дает возможности получить массив байтов.

Comment: Эм? Вы документацию читали? В частности зачем у вас false написано

Comment: Я и true пробовал. не пашет!

Comment: «Не пашет» это не описание проблемы. Что именно не так?

Comment: Или у вас проблема превратить бинарную строку в массив?

Comment: https://www.tehplayground.com/BJoRbmy7cR2ZYxFp

Answer (score 0):

```
string hash_hmac ( string $algo , string $data , string $key [, bool $raw_output = false ] )
```

> raw_output
>   Когда установлено в TRUE, выводит необработанные двоичные данные. При FALSE выводит данные в шестнадцатеричной кодировке в нижнем регистре.

Не то?

Comment: Мне надо вот такой вывод 105
240
151
194
180
175
95
125
169
112
107
217
157
46
245
133
38
126